# helm install stable/gocd returns an error

Tags: kubernetes, go-cd, kubernetes-helm

After installing *helm* I'm trying to install *gocd* for containerizing.

Command 
`helm install stable/gocd --name gocd --namespace gocd` is throwing the following error:

> Error: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%!D(MISSING)TILLER: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Please help in resolving this issue. What may be the error? How can I correct it so that *gocd* is installed through *helm*?

Comment: Hi Deepa, what have you already tried to resolve this?

Comment: The error message matches https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4171 Are you on Azure? Or could be https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3447 or https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3347

Answer (score 0):

Install the GoCD Helm chart
Helm is a package manager for Kubernetes. Kubernetes packages are called charts. Charts are curated applications for Kubernetes.

Install the GoCD Helm chart with these commands:

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
helm install stable/gocd --name gocd --namespace gocd
```

Access the GoCD server
After you’ve installed the GoCD helm chart, you should be able to access the GoCD server from the Ingress IP.

The Ingress IP address can be obtained as specified below:

Minikube

```
minikube ip
```

Others

```
ip=$(kubectl get ingress --namespace gocd gocd-server -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}")
echo "http://$ip"
```

It might take a few minutes for the GoCD server to come up for the first time. You can check if the GoCD server is up with this command:

```
kubectl get deployments --namespace gocd
```

The column Available should show 1 for gocd-server.

The GoCD server on startup will look like this.

Now that you have accessed the GoCD server successfully, you will need to configure the Kubernetes elastic agent plugin.